# Meanings of "legacy incumbent" and "back-end"

Tags: meaning

I read a report and encountered two terms "legacy incumbent" and "back-end". Here is the text:

"Workday is continuing to demolish the legacy incumbents selling HR software to large enterprises, and its accounting product is now awaiting an evangelical customer to accelerate adoption. Workday is one of a number of enterprise IT companies that seem to be combining consumer internet behaviour (product/user focus, rapid iteration, web interface, mobile delivery) with an enterprise sales force. Unlisted Docusign is of similar ilk with a consumer-oriented product, but an enterprise back-end and sales force."

I think legacy incumbent is kind of legacy/heritage company. But I'm not quite sure about the back-end. Is it a term in software engineering like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends or is it just an enterprise support force who works behind?

Comment: You got legacy incumbents right: think SAP, PeopleSoft, Oracle. The subtext is big, old, lumbering dinosaurs. And you got backend right too: the subtext is the front-end, the people-facing part, is friendly, fresh, simple, easy, but the workhorse, the engine, the brain behind the deceptively simple face is is powerful, sturdy, scalable, and so on. It's marketing.

Comment: Don't read such drivel! It will rot your mind. Surely you can get some sort of employment where you are not subjected to it.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. :D I just read for information, not implanting it in my head.

Answer (score 2):

In *How to Speak Money* (2014), John Lanchester writes that "back end" is the out-of-sight stuff that goes on in a business that the customer usually does not notice. He suggests that some of the most important innovations in business are in the back end; for example, bar codes changed all sorts of business operations in ways that the customer never really sees.

A "legacy incumbent" is a finance term describing an established business with a kind of settled procedural infrastructure. The incumbent may be threatened with different, usually newer technologies and procedures. Such incumbent businesses could be vulnerable to an upstart operation that runs on a more advanced digital model. Amazon and Uber are obvious examples.

Comment: Thanks for bringing me a broader context. Things become clear now.